# Excel (365) Create array that shows matching values within long text cell

Tags: search, indexing, excel-formula

I'm using Excel for MS 365 and I could not find how to assemble either a text or an array of pieces of a long text that has match values of another column.
I Tried to use TEXTJOIN, but all my attempts retrieved errors, and the closest formula I could find was: `index($A$2:$A$31,match(1,index(isnumber(search(" "&A$2:$A$31&" "," "&c2&" "))+0,0),0))` , however it retrieves me only first value matched.

Scenario is:
First column I listed most common ingredients used in cooking
Second column I listed the appliances available
Third Column I am copying the full text of recipes (lines would increased thru time)
Forth and fifth columns are where I'm interested on create the formula.

I'll focus in just one cell, to make easier to understand the scenario and try to have somebody offering me a formula. Kindly ask help.

Example of a small hypothetical case, Cell `D2` would show  "Flour Butter Milk" because at cell `C2` contains a long text of cake recipe listing ingredients and instructions.

If I use `index($A$2:$A$8,match(1,index(isnumber(search(" "&A$2:$A$8&" "," "&c2&" "))+0,0),0))` it retrieves me only Flour.

I will replicate same formula concept to create the comparison of `C2` with the range of `$B$2:$B$5` to create value "Mixer 10-in round pan"
Table would look like

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Ingredients** | **Appliances** | **Recipe** | **IngUsed** | **AppUsed** |
| 2 | Flour | Planetary Mixer | *A (see below) | formula | formula |
| 3 | Sugar | Blender |  |  |  |
| 4 | Butter | 10-in round pan |  |  |  |
| 5 | Salt | Air Fryer |  |  |  |
| 6 | Chocolate |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | Milk |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | Corn Oil |  |  |  |  |

*A would be a long text (also with CRLF) like

> 1 cup white sugar ½ cup unsalted butter 2 large eggs 2 teaspoons
> vanilla extract 1 ½ cups all-purpose flour 1 ¾ teaspoons baking powder
> ½ cup milk Directions Gather all ingredients. Overhead of white cake
> ingredients in various bowls and measuring cups. Preheat the oven to
> 350 degrees F (175 degrees C). Grease and flour a 9-inch square cake
> pan. Cream sugar and butter together in a mixing bowl. Add eggs, one
> at a time, beating briefly after each addition. Mix in vanilla. High
> angle of cake batter being mixed in a standing mixer with milk and
> flour in bowls off to the side.  Combine flour and baking powder in a
> separate bowl. Add to the wet ingredients and mix well. Add milk and
> stir until smooth. Flour being added to a cake batter in a standing
> mixer.  Overhead of a creamy cake batter in a bowl.  Pour batter into
> the prepared 10-in round pan. Overhead of a cake batter in a cake pan.
> Bake in the preheated oven until the top springs back when lightly
> touched, 30 to 40 minutes. Overhead of a baked white cake in a cake
> pan. Remove from the oven and cool completely. Enjoy!

Number of lines on column A, B and C are way too higher, I'm just bringing a subset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 you could use the following:

`=TOCOL(REPT(A2:A8,SEARCH(A2:A8,C2)^0),2)` and
`=LET(b,TOCOL(B2:B8,1),TOCOL(REPT(b,SEARCH(b,$C2)^0),2))`

[image]

Comment: Because you need to make sure the cells below `D2` are all empty (select all, press del-key).

Comment: And the reason both formulas are different is A2:A8 are all non-blank, so no need to filter out blanks. The second formula starts with filtering out the blanks in `B2:B8` this simulates `B2:B5`

Comment: I assume I should use the second formula.

Both formula retrieved SPILL! error. Checked the first formula array was {"","Flour"}
Second was {"Flour Sugar Butter Salt Milk",""}. This is close to the desired

I saw results over D2:D6, however, as said, cells at C would increase, meaning C3 will have a recipe of a grilled chicken breast, C4 a Corn Cream. Desired value would be in D2 a string "Flour Sugar Butter Salt Milk". D3 would would be "Salt Corn Oil".
Would be a case of using TOROW instead TOCOL?

Comment: Spill error is caused by data already being in the range within the area of the result of the formula. By clicking the formula cell you can see where it intends to spill to. The way you shared it should be TOCOL. See screenshot in my answer. Formula is pasted in `D2` only (not `D3,D4`, etc.)

Comment: If you wrap it in `ARRAYROTEXT()` it'll show the results comma separated in one cell.

Comment: Hello P.b
I used ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL(REPT($A$2:$A$10,SEARCH($A$2:$A$10,C2)^0),2)) and copied to all C cells below, so C2 retrieved "Flour, Sugar, Butter, Salt, Milk", and C3 retrived "Chicken Breasts" as I inserted "Chicken Breasts" at A9 cell.
Worked perfectly. Thanks for the tip

Comment: The other formula works, but spills to the cells below.